# Cytoscape 3.8.2: downloaded the latest version but can't find CytoscapeConfiguration anywhere to drop the dummy file

Tags: cytoscape

Downloaded the latest version but can't find CytoscapeConfiguration anywhere to drop the dummy file. When I search my computer, nothing comes up for that in the search bar. Any suggestions? Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: image showing where i downloaded the app to]

[image: image showing that nothing returns when i search for the directory]

Answer (score 0):

CytoscapeConfiguration should be in your home directory.  If it's not there, you should be able to just create it, but it is supposed to be created automatically when you first start up Cytoscape.

-- scooter